# How to Insert into a database values from a JSON Payload in MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am using an MVC application to display information about an Issue from a webhook Json Payload.  The application runs on real-time functionality (using deserialization and signalr).  The application is listening for when the webhook is firing and it will send an email whether the application is running on the browser or not.

How ever the way I would like to keep a record of the information from the application when the Json payload is deserialized automatically insert it into the database so that it can be displayed later.

```
Public Function PostIssueData(iss As iTable) as ActionResult
    Dim db As New Database
    db.iTable.Add(iss)
    db.SaveChanges()

    return view()
End Function
```

I don't think this way is possible as I am reading in a Json payload so the table would just have null values and insert nothing.

I am reading the data like this:

```
Dim r As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
Dim rawJson As String = r.ReadToEnd()
Dim iss As rObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of rOject)(rawJson)
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(rawJson)
```

So I would have to use this data to insert into a database and have it done automatically, how can this be done?

Update - This worked using Entity framework like this.

```
Dim newIssue As New IssueResultTable
newIssue.issueKey = issue.issue.key
newIssue.status = issue.issue.fields.status.name

Using db As New GartanIssueTrackerEntities
      db.IssueResultTables.Add(newIssue)
      db.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Comment: Have you considered Entity Framework? It allows you to work with your class objects directly.

Comment: Yes I have, how could I implement it correctly to work with my class objects so it automatically updates my database

Comment: Set it up to use `code first`. There are many good tutorials [online, see this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907)

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using database first - code first is not possible

Comment: This also shows you how to use database first; this should be fine as long as you have a table matching your object.

Comment: Never mind it was working it just wasn't refreshing correctly in the mvc application